# Oracle database as a single synchronization point for two separate web applications

Tags: oracle, concurrency

I am considering using an Oracle database to synchronize concurrent operations from two or more web applications on separate servers. The database is the single infrastructure element in common for those applications.

There is a good chance that two or more applications will attempt to perform the same operation at the exact same moment (cron invoked). I want to use the database to let one application decide that it will be the one which will do the work, and that the others will not do it at all.

The general idea is to perform a somehow-atomic and visible to all connections select/insert with node's ID. Only node which has the same id as the first inserted node ID returned by select would be do the work.

It was suggested to me that a merge statement can be of use here. However, after doing some research, I found a discussion which states that [the merge statement is not designed to be called](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2298054?tstart=0)

Another option is to lock a table. By definition, only one node will be able to lock the server and do the insert, then select. After the lock is removed, other instances will see the inserted value and will not perform work.

What other solutions would you consider? I frown on workarounds with random delays, or even using oracle exceptions to notify a node that it should not do the work. I'd prefer a clean solution.

Comment: The `dbms_lock` package will do exactly what you want. This is just a wrapper around the locks Oracle itself uses for its operations. I wouldn't do it any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. It works as intended. It is important to remember to commit the transaction as soon as the needed update is made, so that other nodes don't hang waiting for the value.